# Producer, consumer POSIX

Tags: c, concurrency, posix, ipc

I am trying to write simple producer consumer app using C POSIX semaphores.
Consumer:

```
int memoryID;
struct wrapper *memory;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    key_t sharedMemoryKey = ftok(".",MEMORY_KEY);
    if(sharedMemoryKey==-1)
    {
        perror("ftok():");
        exit(1);
    }

    memoryID=shmget(sharedMemoryKey,sizeof(struct wrapper),0);

    if(memoryID==-1)
    {
        perror("shmget(): ");
        exit(1);
    }

    memory = shmat(memoryID,NULL,0);
    if(memory== (void*)-1)
    {
        perror("shmat():");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        int r = rand();
        sem_wait(&memory->full);
        sem_wait(&memory->mutex);
        int n;
        sem_getvalue(&memory->full,&n);
        printf("Removed item: %d",(memory->array)[n]);
        usleep(1000000);
        sem_post(&memory->mutex);
        sem_post(&memory->empty);
    }

}
```

Producer:

```
int memoryID;
struct wrapper *memory;
int rc;

void atexit_function() {
    rc = shmctl(memoryID, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    rc = shmdt(memory);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    atexit(atexit_function);
    //creating key for shared memory
    srand(time(NULL));
    key_t sharedMemoryKey = ftok(".", MEMORY_KEY);
    if (sharedMemoryKey == -1) {
        perror("ftok():");
        exit(1);
    }

    memoryID = shmget(sharedMemoryKey, sizeof(struct wrapper), IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    if (memoryID == -1) {
        perror("shmget():");
        exit(1);
    }

    memory = shmat(memoryID, NULL, 0);
    if (memory == (void *) -1) {
        perror("shmat():");
        exit(1);
    }

    //initialization
    memset(&memory->array, 0, sizeof(memory->array));
    sem_init(&memory->mutex, 1, 1);
    sem_init(&memory->empty, 1, SIZE_OF_ARRAY);
    sem_init(&memory->full, 1, 0);

    if (memoryID == -1) {
        perror("shmget(): ");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        int r = rand();
        sem_wait(&memory->empty);
        sem_wait(&memory->mutex);
        int n;
        sem_getvalue(&memory->full,&n);
        printf("Adding task\t Value:%d\tNumber of tasks waiting:%d \n",r,n);
        (memory->array)[n]=r;
        usleep(1000000);
        sem_post(&memory->mutex);
        sem_post(&memory->full);
    }

}
```

common.h:

```
#define MEMORY_KEY 5
#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY 10

struct wrapper
{
    int array[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
    sem_t empty;
    sem_t mutex;
    sem_t full;
};
```

What is happening:

Producer is starting successfully

Producer is successfully adding elements to table and printing them out Quickly after starting  producer,

I am starting consumer Consumer does not take element from
    array even once

Producer fills up the array and is waiting

I do not really see where is the problem. I suspect that the problem is the implementation not the algorithm cause the algorithm is taken from wikipedia [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem#Using_semaphores)

Comment: You might want to run your programs under the `strace` tool, a great debugging aid so you can see what the programs are  doing.  Also, to be sure you're not fooled by buffering, insert a newline in your consumer  printf() statement, or call fflush(stdout) after calling printf.

Comment: there seems to be several #include statements missing from both source files.

Comment: you should add the standard (do not include me more than once) wrapper in the common.h file:  #ifndef COMMON_H  #define COMMON_H ..... #endif // COMMON_H

Comment: parameters 'argc' and 'argv[]' are not being used, so the compiler will raise a warning for each of those parameters.  suggest using 'int main( void )'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your consumer works fine. It's just not flushing to stdout. Do as nos suggested by putting a `\n` at the end of your consumer `printf` call. You can also see it working by just waiting longer. Your producer will start producing again after the consumer has executed a few iterations.